# call method from a method within the same class

Tags: methods, collision-detection, method-call

I have a platformer class that creates a window and spawns platforms and a "character". It uses another class platform to make platforms. The character is supposed to jump up and land on the platforms. I use the `getBounds` and `getTopY` functions for collision detection but they only work for the first platform. How can i get them to work for multiple platforms?

```
public class Platformer extends JPanel {
    Platform platform = new Platform(this);
    Character character = new Character(this);

    public Platformer() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                character.keyTyped(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                character.keyReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                character.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        platform.Location(150,200);
        platform.paint(g2d);

        platform.Location(200,120);
        platform.paint(g2d);

        character.paint(g2d);
    }

    private void move(){
        character.move();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");

        //create new game
        Platformer platformer = new Platformer();                

        //add game
        frame.add(platformer);

        //size
        frame.setSize(400, 400);            
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //set close condition
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {          
            platformer.move();
            platformer.repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);//sleep for 10 sec 
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Platform {
    private static final int Height = 10;
    private static final int Width = 60;
    int x;
    int Y;
    private Platformer platformer;

    public Platform(Platformer platformer) {
        this.platformer = platformer;
    }

    public void Location(int xin, int yin) {
        x = xin;
        Y = yin;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {       
        g.fillRect(x, Y, Width, Height);       
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, Y, Width, Height);
    }

    public int getTopPlat() {
        return Y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have only one platform. And you draw this platform twice in different places (`paint` function in `Platformer`):

```
platform.Location(150,200);
platform.paint(g2d);

platform.Location(200,120);
platform.paint(g2d);
```

Therefore I suppose you handle only one platform (with coordinates 200 and 120). You must keep all of your platforms and handle each of them separately.